# how do i solve this mistake i'm going crazy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, react-native-ios

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6rCE.jpg)

How do i fix?

I'm getting this error when creating a project.

Might not support the new mac version?
MacOS 11.0.1

Comment: Hey Ahmed, how did you create the project? Did you change anything after creating the project?

Comment: I created it by typing 'react-native init <projectname>'. Normally there was no such problem, but when I wanted to work today, I got an error like this.

Answer (score 0):

They wrote what should you try (`npm audit fix`). As you can see, there is problem in some of your files.

[image]

Comment: I saw that the pod install file was not added to ios and I added it manually by pod-install, there is no problem at the moment.